# as3 call class to main fla

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash

I'm trying to call a class to my main flash file in as3.

my class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Snow extends MovieClip
    {
        private var flakesVector:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
        private var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000);

        public function Snow(speed:int = 3, flakesNumber = 100 ):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < flakesNumber; i++)
            {
                var flake:Snowflake = new Snowflake();

                flake.vel = (Math.random() * speed) + 0.5;
                flake.xSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * (0.5 - -0.5 + 1)) + -0.5;

                flake.scaleX = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.3;
                flake.scaleY = flake.scaleX;
                flake.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                flake.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

                addChild(flake);

                flakesVector.push(flake);
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fall);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, changeMovement);
            timer.start();
        }

        private function fall(e:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < flakesVector.length; i++)
            {
                flakesVector[i].x += flakesVector[i].xSpeed;
                flakesVector[i].y += flakesVector[i].vel;

                if(flakesVector[i].y > stage.stageHeight)
                {
                    flakesVector[i].x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    flakesVector[i].y = -flakesVector[i].height;
                }
            }
        }

        private function changeMovement(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < flakesVector.length; i++)
            {
                flakesVector[i].xSpeed *= -1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And in my main fla i try to call it like this:

```
import classes.Snow;

var Snowy:Snow = new Snow();
addChild(Snowy);
```

But when i try to do it if i dont give any instance name to my snowflake movieclip i get "Cannot acess a property or method of a null object reference" and if i name my instance snowflake i get the error "type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Snowflake"

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT:

but if i call the class document as Snow I get a lot of errors:
any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: yes I already did it but I still get stuck in the same place with the error "type was not found or was not compile time constant:Snowflake" maybe it doesn't find the movieclip in my library but I have him there with the name "Snowflake" and export to ActionScript with the class name "Snowflake".

Comment: your class has no package scope defined (it's only 'package') but yet you import it with a package scope: "classes". That already cannot work.

Comment: yes I know I can do it like that but I want to make the class being called by a button, and like that the class is always active. Basically I want to turn on and off the snow, is it possible in this way? @esdebon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// import classes.Snow; // <---- REMOVE THIS

var Snowy:Snow;
var snowSW:Boolean=false;

button.addEventListener(MouesEvent.CLICK, switchSnow);

function switchSnow(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(!snowSW){
       Snowy= new Snow();
       addChild(Snowy);
     }else{
       removeChild(Snowy);
       Snowy= null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to ajust a little bit but it is now working! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Where is your class?? is next to your fla file??

then only use:

```
var Snowy:Snow = new Snow();
addChild(Snowy);
```

Or in your properties panel

in class type: Snow

[image]

**EDIT: Your code work fine**

[image: Working]